# Content Organiser - Ammending the custom splash screen

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to be able to remove the url from the content organiser splash screen. Has anyone done this before i go crazy.

[image]

Comment: has anyone got any clues ?? Or even remove it so it doesnt even run.

Comment: if i use officialfile.asmx to submit the documnet within a workflow - i will not get the splash screens ?? Is this correct , if so any idea who i can implement the url via workflow ??

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to say a few words, without really having a solution that I can suggest.

### The context

Being on SharePoint Online and in the presence of a file in the _layouts folder (/_layouts/15/routermessage.aspx), editing the file's contents or tweaking it in any way is not possible, so whatever you do, it will not be easy.

### Content Organizer

The first thing I would suggest is to actually check the reasons behind using content routing and whether or not you can simply disable it.

Instead of trying to fix something that's not broken, maybe you realize you don't really need the organizer and then you'll be on your way.

### The workflow approach

This has been successfully accomplished before (not by me) but it might need special effort.

[Drop Off Library - Custom Edit Form - Submit button?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3403752e-4fd6-465f-8904-909a054f1130/drop-off-library-custom-edit-form-submit-button?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)

> One possible option is to create a SPD Workflow against the 'Drop Off
>   Library' which runs the 'Send Document to Repository' action
>   (affectively submitting back to itself to fire the content organizer)
>
> If [WFCondition_CheckYourMandatoryFieldsAreNotEmpty]
>
> Submit File using Move to the
>   http:///_vti_bin/OfficialFile.asmx with Routing Document
>   (Output to Variable: Submitted file)
>
> Set it to run 'on change' (not on create).. and make sure you have at
>   least mandatory field specified (which is checked for in the Workflow
>   IF condition)

Another option:

[Creating Items in Drop-Off Library via SPD Workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60341/creating-items-in-drop-off-library-via-spd-workflow)

### Custom Edit Forms / Custom code

If you create a new edit form, you can either give away the Publish functionality (happens to newly created forms) or use a copy of EditForm.aspx.

For example, you can potentially stop publishing immediately, and (if I'm not wrong) documents get published by a [daily timer job](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b9409e31-a5cc-4608-8b30-0b8b7a45b852/content-organizer-processing-in-sharepoint-online?forum=SP2016).

This can also open up room for something custom, such as a especial submit button.

[This post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160829044525/http://blog.scosby.com/post/2011/03/16/SharePoint-2010-Content-Organizer-Client-Object-Model.aspx) is a bit old but has an interesting take on client side file uploads on a content organizer enabled site.

In conclusion, I don't think there's any easy trick to this. You can/should give workflows a try, but you might be better off disabling content organizer or stop publishing immediately to avoid getting to that screen.

Comment: all seems exactly where I got to, I was looking for a solution to overwriting the splash screen not a different approach... also the Send Document to Repository is not there with SPD workflow on the SharePoint online platform. but thanks anyway...